# Rails ActiveRecord Sum with conditions not working

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

In my view I call a function

```
def sum_customer_yearly_revenue(customer_id, year)
  sum_customer_yearly_revenue = Sale.sum(:net_amount, :conditions => ['customer_id = ? AND financial_year = ?', customer_id, year])
end
```

For some reason SQL sent to Postgresql (as viewed in log files) is follows:

```
SELECT SUM("sales"."net_amount") AS sum_id FROM "sales"
```

All the conditions are being ignored.

Has anyone experienced this before and can give me some insight?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update the `sum_customer_yearly_revenue` method as

For **`Rails 3.x`**

```
def sum_customer_yearly_revenue(customer_id, year)
  Sale.where(:all, :conditions => ['customer_id = ? AND financial_year = ?', customer_id, year]).sum(:net_amount)
end
```

For **`Rails 4.x`**

```
def sum_customer_yearly_revenue(customer_id, year)
  Sale.where(customer_id: customer_id, financial_year: year).sum(:net_amount)
end
```

Comment: Thank you that worked brilliantly! I was originally running Rails 4.0 and upgraded to 4.1. Was the ".where(:all, :conditions => ['customer_id = ? ...) etc deprecated?

Comment: Glad to help :) And Yes, it has been deprecated.